# How to use crontab and mutt properly?

Tags: 14.04, cron, mutt

I would like to automatically send emails via `mutt`. I have configured `mutt` and its works fine when using:

```
echo "Hi" | mutt -s "Hu Hu" -a /home/.../some.pdf  -- me@gmx.com
```

However when using `crontab` no email is sent.

```
00 17 * * * echo "Hi" | mutt -s "Hu Hu" -a /home/.../some.pdf  -- me@gmx.com
```

I tried as well:

```
00 17 * * * sudo echo "Hi" | mutt -s "Hu Hu" -a /home/.../some.pdf  -- me@gmx.com
```

Other cronjobs work fine except sending mails with `mutt`. May I ask for some advice?

Comment: I think this is likely to be related to the difference in the $PATH from your user's command line environment to the path when scripts are run from cron.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the full path, so omething like /usr/bin/mutt. Also check the user cron is running as and the users that are allowed to use mutt.